# Skype error? Or Eclipse error?

Tags: java, eclipse, skype

I tried making a simple project for my skype-bot, and it looks like this:

```
import com.skype.Skype;
import com.skype.SkypeException;

public class SkypeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SkypeException {
        System.out.println(Skype.getVersion());
    }
}
```

But when i started it i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.skype.SkypeException: Loading libskype.jnilib failed.
at com.skype.Utils.convertToSkypeException(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.Utils.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.Skype.getVersion(Unknown Source)
at SkypeDemo.main(SkypeDemo.java:6)
Caused by: com.skype.connector.LoadLibraryException: Loading libskype.jnilib failed.
at com.skype.connector.ConnectorUtils.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.osx.SkypeFramework.init(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.osx.OSXConnector.initializeImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.assureAttached(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

So how do I fix this error? Keep in mind I have both Skype jars in the build path.

Answer (score 5):

The error is telling you that it cannot load a native library ("libskype.jnilib").  This is (probably) neither Eclipse or Skype's fault.

It is most likely your fault because either the native library is not where it needs to be (or you haven't told Eclipse where to look), or because you have the wrong flavour of native code (DLL, .so or whatever)

(If there was another chained "cause" in the stack trace, it might tell you more ...)

Reference:

- This blog post explains how to add a native library to an Eclipse project - http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49342.html  (In fact, it describes two ways ...)

Comment: @javawarrior You need to add the native library to your Eclipse project's build path.

Comment: i did this, and it STILL doesn't recognize it

Comment: Have you checked that the native lib is the right kind for the JVM you are using?  E.g. a 32-bit DLL (or whatever) is required for a 32-bit JVM.  If that fails, I suggest that you try to download the source code, build with debug symbols, and debug it.